# Is there any way to fetch the original password from MySQL through PHP which is protected by md5() method?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to fetch the original password value from DB i.e. MySQL through PHP for my own home purpose. It will not a private work area I am just testing my code and queries for the practice results.

Suppose I have filled a password "abc123" and it is protected by md5() method and stored in the table like as "adbb@1225485fdhgfhdfdff" but I want this value "abc123" from the table in PHP code if possible in any way. Here is my code:

```
<?php
 $a=$_POST['pass'];
 $pro_pass=md5($a);
?>
```

How we can fetch the original value of password from tables using select query in PHP. Please help if possible in any way through code or query.

Comment: Hashes - even MD5 - are irreversible; you lose the original data when you hash it (it's a digest of the message, not the message itself). However, MD5 is so outdated now, with so many flaws discovered, that it can be brute-forced.

Comment: there's no decryption for md5 once you encrypted it

Comment: `nd5()` is not safe to use, please use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: Unless the password is salted, you can try one of several online services that offer an MD5-decryption using rainbow tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve from md5, Because it is `Cryptographic hash function`, and it is one way.

So you can only get `hash value` of given string using md5 but can not retrieve original string using md5.

Comment: You don't *encrypt* the string - you hash it... I wish people would stop equating hashing with encryption - they're two different things : http://www.securityinnovationeurope.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-hashing-and-encrypting

Comment: Hello @CD001 , Sir if we can't reverse the md5() method value then any other in PHP and MySQL where I can store password in protected form and get it back in original form... If possible then please let me know here,
thanks!

Comment: @KamalHasija - you don't want to; passwords should **never** be retrievable by anyone - including yourself - it's more secure that way. You should store a salted hash of the password in the database and when someone logs in you use the same salt and the same hashing algorithm to generate the salted hash from the password entered. You just then compare that to what's in the database - if it matches, you're good to go.

Comment: @CD001- But I don't know the exact meaning of salt hash for passwords, how I can use it very easily! Please let me know if there is any example about this...

Comment: @KamalHasija - just use PHP's `password_hash()` function; it deals with the salt for you : http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php